# DynamoDB for bank transactions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

I am thinking to simulate a bank account like transaction in a dynamodb
Being a noSQL type database, would this use case be suited for dynamodb?
Or should I stick with SQL based database?

Does anyone know how do banks usually handles this?
Do they use something like DynamoDB or do they keep our transaction in a separate table?

Comment: In short, Dynamodb does not support transactions like a relational database. Have a power outage in a SQL database and your system will come back up in a consistent state. Have a power outage in DynamoDB and it quite possibly won't One of the key requirements of a banking system is that when you pay a merchant, $100 comes out of your account and $100 goes into their account. This is not guaranteed on databases like DynamoDB. I suggest you do some reading on ATOMicity and perhaps this too: https://www.dailycred.com/article/dynamodb-shortcomings-and-work-arounds

Comment: So.. theoretically, dynamodb is definitely not suitable for a production bank transaction system. But if you just want to simulate one, no problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementation of Atomic Transactions in dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664966/implementation-of-atomic-transactions-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SQL based system allows transactions across multiple tables, while DynamoDB only allows transactions at the individual item.  However, there is a [DynamoDB transaction library](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-transaction-library/) for Java that allows atomic transactions across multiple items at the expense of speed and substantially more writes per request.

DynamoDB does support [atomic counters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters), which are bank-account-like (the example on the documentation page is along those line).

DynamoDB also provides [conditional writes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html) which can help avoid certain type of race conditions when an item is attempted to be updated concurrently.

Could you build a suitable system on top of DynamoDB? Maybe, but this all really depends on your specific requirements and how you go about implementing such a system.  That said, DynamoDB does provide some functionality that I outlined above to address the types of concerns that arise when building such a system.

Comment: you forgot to mention the atomic counter is not really reliable as mentioned from their page.

Comment: What is the constraint of DynamoDB Atomic Counter? As DynamoDB does not natively support transaction across tables, what can't we do with DynamoDB transactions as we do in SQL transactions?

Answer (score 3):

In 2018, DynamoDB now has transaction support for reading and writing items in multiple tables within a single region. It is not exactly the same as SQL transactions, because transactions may fail and return an error if the data is modified by another parallel operation, but it is ACID.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/